# Keep default value in the destination table when do fast load in SSIS

Tags: ssis

For fast load, is there anyway to keep the default value in the target table even I check `Keep nulls` in the destination?

Similar to `FIRE_Trigger`, any configuration that can be set to keep the default value?

Thanks

Comment: Don't map the column and the database should generate the default value.

Comment: hi @EzLo, if I check the `Keep nulls`, it wont, it works only if I did not check it..

Comment: Oh my bad, if you check `keep nulls` then the default will be ignored as the insert statement will explicitly insert nulls. There is no clean workaround that I know of. You can generate the default value in your data flow or update it on your table afterwards.